# How can I read user input to an array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, user-input

OK, so I am trying to make a program using Visual Basic that will allow the user to add links to web pages (such as `www.google.ca`) to a list in the program and make it so that they do not dissapear once the program is closed.

So to get into more detail, I have a text box, a listview, and a button. When the user types a link into the text box it needs to be put into an array (called "addlink") and then when the user presses the button, the link is typed into the listview as an object.

Then if the user clicks on that object in the listview, it will open up the browser using the **`WebBrowser`** command. How do I set the text in the textbox to an array once the button is clicked?

This program greatly resembles most Internet browser's bookmarking feature. :D

Specifications:

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate Edition
- Software: Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express
- Experience with Visual Basic: Average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about adding to an array. You could do something like this.

```
Dim addlink() As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If IsNothing(addlink) Then
        ReDim addlink(0)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve addlink(addlink.Count)
    End If

    addlink(UBound(addlink)) = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or to use a collection like @Cody Gray suggested

```
Dim addlink As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    addlink.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure. But why not use a collection type specifically designed to be dynamically resizable, like [`List(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or [`Collection(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)? There's absolutely *no* reason to be writing `ReDim` and `ReDim Preserve` in VB.NET...

Comment: is the above code an error free example? if so how could i test it out to view it in action, ive tried simply copying it into a new VB2010 project and building it but the buttons didnt come up in the designer window of my software, i think i need to add them manually am i right?

Comment: also, is this the code for the whole program or just the objects like buttons and listview?

Comment: This is code for the button click event. you need to add your buttons. I just showed you the array definition and how to dynamically adjust the array size.

Comment: @Cody Gray You are right, I was focused on what @daniel11 was asking not on how to do it more efficiently

Comment: So far everything you have suggested has worked. However i still need to be able to show the array in a list (via either listview, listbox, or link labels) im thinking link labels would be easier to add, maybe theres a way to add a link and set its value to equal an element in the array. In that case, the same could be accomplished with a listview, just add an item and set its value to equal an array element. however i dont know how to do any of that i was just throwing out ideas.

Answer (score 0):

edit: I have removed my answer, which was specific to VB6, but left the portion of my answer that made suggestions:

You will need an edit bookmark and remove bookmark feature.

You could make the textbox multi-line and allow the user to input multiple links at once... or you can do one at a time.  The only difference is that you would have to cut the text up every time there was a chr(13) & chr(10), using Mid (to do the actually cutting) and inStr (to figure out where to cut.)

Logically separating the "titles" of the bookmarks from the URLs would be ideal.  For example, you might have 3 links to different cook.com recipes (we'll say chicken, lamb, and stir fry), but the URLs might resemble something like `http://www.cook.com/recipes/2389047291`, which doesn't exactly inform the user which link they want if they want a specific recipe.  Using two text boxes, you could allow the user to logical separate the titles and the URL, e.g. List1: Cook.com Stir Fry... List2: http://www.cook.com/recipes/2389047291  (Alternatively, you could just hide the URL altogether, displaying only the page titles to the user.)

Comment: The question is actually about VB.NET. Visual Basic 2010 Express is not the same language as VB 6. Has it really been 10 years since you used VB.NET?

Comment: The title was originally "VB," and there was no mention of .NET or a .NET tag.  It did say "Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express" once, but I did not recognize it as being completely different than VB6.  I will remove the portion of the answer specific to VB6, but leave the recommendations.  Sorry for any confusion.  :)

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft's naming has confused people before. Visual Basic and Windows CE are shining examples of how not to reuse product names for what are basically entirely different things. And while functions like `Mid` and `InStr` are supported in VB.NET for backwards-compatibility reasons, they're not necessarily the recommended .NET way of doing things. I fixed the question in an attempt to minimize confusion.

Comment: Could either of you give me an example code, along with a quick description of each line so i can learn how to do this easily later on. Thanks!